# How to charge and use a salvaged laptop battery with BMS?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have salvaged a laptop battery but I have no idea how I can use it like a normal battery. It does have a 10 pins connector but I have no idea what they are doing and how I can use them.

[image]

[image]

Should I just cut the metal stripes (separate the 3 cells) and use another BMS, or is there a way to use the same BMS without the computer mainboard ?

Comment: You should not attempt to do anything with this.

Comment: I expected this answer and I appreciate your concern.

Comment: These batteries have a very high energy density and can explode or burn if not properly managed.

Comment: which is why I'm trying to use the existing BMS. Is there like a PCB board that have a 10 pins like that, and can manage it ?

Answer (score 1):

The connector probably includes connections for SMbus or similar, and a thermistor to go to the host controller. Unless you're willing to reverse-engineer all that stuff, seems like using the pack as-is is a dead end.

That all said, if the laptop was old it is likely the batteries have reached the end of their useful life so it's probably not worth the effort when you can get fresh new cells with an integrated safety circuit as a ready-to-use assembly.

Comment: I had my hands on several old laptops with 18650 batteries (for a DIY power pack) but they were all around 1.8V. (Dead right ?) Now I have 3 others of these flat type lithium battery from 3 different laptops. And that's the sad thing the laptops are broken but their battery are working well...